# jQuery event on click handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have two two `<p>` and one `<div>` and want event handler to display a message when the *first* `<p>` is pressed. How can I pull that off?

```js
$("#menu:first-child").on('click', 'p', pullInput);

function pullInput() {
  console.log("da");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <p id="newCategoryButton">New category</p>
  <p>New Song</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use ID `newCategoryButton`?`$("#menu").on('click','#newCategoryButton',pullInput);`?

Comment: Why the event delegation?

Comment: @guradio is right. Or even more simple - `$("#newCategoryButton").on("click", pullInput );`

Comment: The paragraphs elements have opacity 0 first and when I press a button they have opacity 1,maiby they act like dinamicaly created elements because none of the examples are working.The only one is this  "$("#menu").on('click','p',pullInput);" but it gets both of the paragraphs

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong. Update your selector like this

```js
$("#menu p:first-child").on('click', pullInput);
function pullInput(){
  console.log("HI!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <p id="newCategoryButton">New category</p>
  <p>New Song</p>
</div>
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9amv3vmh/

Comment: The paragraphs elements have opacity 0 first and when I press a button they have opacity 1,maiby they act like dinamicaly created elements because none of the examples are working.The only one is this "$("#menu").on('click','p',pullInput);" but it gets both of the paragraphs

Comment: Can you show us the fiddle... i mean including the button, on clicking which opacity changes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:first-child` selector with `p` element.

```
$("#menu").on('click','p:first-child',pullInput);
```

```js
$("#menu").on('click', 'p:first-child', pullInput);

function pullInput() {
  console.log("da");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <p id="newCategoryButton">New category</p>
  <p>New Song</p>
</div>
```

---

However as you have sepecified `ID` with `p` element use it to bind event handler.

```
$("#newCategoryButton").on('click', pullInput);
```

Comment: The paragraphs elements have opacity 0 first and when I press a button they have opacity 1,maiby they act like dinamicaly created elements because none of the examples are working.The only one is this "$("#menu").on('click','p',pullInput);" but it gets both of the paragraphs

Comment: @S.Georgian, Can you create Fiddle or snippet to show the issue?